# AesCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net

```
byte[] pText = null;
byte[] encryptedData = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text);
var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
int nBytes = aes.BlockSize >> 3;
byte[] iv = new byte[nBytes];
for (int i = 0; i < iv.Length; i++)
    iv[i] = encryptedData[i];

using (var bobAlgorithm = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(bobKey))
using (CngKey alicePubKey =
          CngKey.Import(alicePubKeyBlob, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob))
{
    byte[] symmKey = bobAlgorithm.DeriveKeyMaterial(alicePubKey);
    aes.Key = symmKey;
    aes.IV = iv;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cs =
            new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    //ms.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);
    cs.Write(encryptedData, nBytes, encryptedData.Length - nBytes);
    cs.Close();
    pText = ms.ToArray();
    textBox3.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(pText);
    aes.Clear();
}
```

ошибка "Входные данные не являются полным блоком"

выдает ошибку в строчке

```
cs.Close();
```

---

процедура шифрования:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] pText = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
    byte[] encryptedData = null;
    CreateKeys();
    using (var aliceAlgorithm = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(aliceKey))
    using (CngKey bobPubKey =
                CngKey.Import(bobPubKeyBlob, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob))
    {
        byte[] symmKey = aliceAlgorithm.DeriveKeyMaterial(bobPubKey);
        using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aes.Key = symmKey;
            aes.GenerateIV();
            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor())
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                ms.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);
                cs.Write(pText, 0, pText.Length);
                cs.Close();
                encryptedData = ms.ToArray();
            }
            aes.Clear();
        }
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, судя по всему, в [`Padding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.padding.aspx).

Вы устанавливаете

```
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
```

а затем декодируете сообщение, длина которого не кратна длине блока.

А как вы зашифровывали сообщение?

Comment: Padding я уже добавил когда искал решение проблемы в интернете, как с ним так и без него результата 0.

Код енкрипта http://www.ex.ua/view_storage/314655805426
PS: не могу сбросить код сюда, из-за низкого рейтинга

Comment: а  так же несколько часов пробуя разные решения я заметил что у меня поток MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); пуст, и я не понимаю почему

Comment: Хм, сразу какая-то нестыковка. Вы отдаёте зашифрованный текст как base64, а читаете как utf8.

---
Если у вас шифровка не меняет Padding, то и расшифровка не должна. Там наверняка и другие ошибки, пока все не исправите, не заработает.

Comment: исправил, теперь исключений нет, только пустой textbox

Comment: Ну, а вы пробовали пройти под отладчиком? Что идёт не так? (Кстати, опубликуйте исправленный код же.)

Comment: уже все исправил, спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: ну, так опубликуйте исправления, для потомков :)